# Control host systemd from Docker container

Tags: docker

Is it possible to control host services from a Docker container?

I would like to execute: `systemctl start|stop|status SERVICE_NAME` from my container. I tried to mount `/lib/systemd` but it doesn't work

[EDIT]
I'm switching the logic so all the services I need to control will be in a docker container, and I will control those containers instead. Still curious if it's possible to do it

Thanks!

Comment: Controlling a host from within a container would seem an enormous security hole. Perhaps a container is the wrong product for your use case.

Comment: Currently all my software stack is running directly on the system, it's just easier for me to manage versions/updates using Docker. It's not a critical system, it's a Mini-PC. Just want to start/stop my other services AND OpenVPN connection.